# How to send two sql queries after getting response of one in oracle database?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Hi i asked a query lastly how to send a query to oracle database and i got a response and now again i am stuck in an problem how to send another pure SQL format query after i send the invoice number to database on connection to oracle database:-
The Previous query i used to send invoice number the value to database was:-

```
    <?php
      $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 83.111.41.30)(PORT = 1536)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TEST)))" ;

      if($c = OCILogon("XXWEBSITE", "xxwebsite", $db))
      {
        $stid = oci_parse($c, "call apps.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_pkg.xx_ar_cust_os_bal_proc('34499', :inv_num, :unit_no, :cust_name, :inv_date, :trans_type, :cust_no, :outstanding_amount, :err)");
            /* Do this for each bind variable */
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":inv_num", $inv_num);
              .........
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":err", $err);
            $check = oci_execute($stid);
                    print_r($check);
       OCILogoff($c);
     }
  else
  {
      $err = OCIError();
      echo "Connection failed.";
  }
?>
```

and now i am having another pure SQL query which i need to send to get the output from the database and i need to send the sql query just after i send the invoice number to database:-

SQL:-

```
   SELECT SUM (aps.amount_due_remaining) Due Amount, ra.trx_number,
         ofc.office, hp.party_name, TO_CHAR (ra.trx_date), rt.NAME,
         hc.account_number
    FROM ar.ra_customer_trx_all ra,
         ar.ar_payment_schedules_all aps,
         ar.ra_cust_trx_types_all rt,
         apps.hz_cust_accounts hc,
         apps.hz_parties hp,
         apps.pn_locations_v ofc
   WHERE 1 = 1
     AND TO_CHAR (ofc.location_id) = ra.attribute5
     AND hc.cust_account_id = aps.customer_id
     AND ra.customer_trx_id = aps.customer_trx_id
     AND ra.org_id = aps.org_id
     AND ra.cust_trx_type_id = rt.cust_trx_type_id
     AND ra.bill_to_customer_id = hc.cust_account_id
     AND hp.party_id = hc.party_id
     AND aps.amount_due_remaining <> 0
     AND TO_CHAR (ofc.location_id) = ra.attribute5
     AND rt.NAME IN
            ('AC Bill ARA', 'ARA - Connection Fee', 'ARA Cooling 
              Deposit',
             'ARA - Demand Charges', 'AC Bill ARR')
     AND ra.trx_number = '34499'
     GROUP BY ofc.suite,
         rt.NAME,
         ra.trx_number,
         ofc.office,
         hp.party_name,
         ra.trx_date,
         rt.NAME
```